# Cannot get custom header value from web api if called too frequently

Tags: httprequest, asp.net-web-api2

I am calling web api services from angularjs. I am setting some custom header before calling the service.  I am getting the value by 
Request.Headers.GetValues. It is working fine.

**But the problem is if I call multiple service immediately I am getting the header null.**

If I use some setTimeout from JavaScript before service call then again it is working fine.

Can anybody let me know what is wrong with my approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You observed this behavior while debugging in VS? or have put some Diagnostics (Debug.writeLine -> Output window)

Comment: Also, can you confirm on client side, if all request sent has this custom headers in browser's developer window -> Network tab.

Comment: Hi @Savaratkar, i am running my application in IIS Express with VS-2013. Yes from client side all requests sent has header value. Even If i call same service multiple time then also there is no header in server